# How do I build a water Ram Pump that will pump 400 feet and 30 feet vertically

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps, water-resources

I'm interested in building a ram pump to pump water from a creek that runs at the bottom of my property to the top where i'm going to make my little homestead. I've seen allot of stuff online on building DIY ram pumps and I had a few questions.

Do I have to use a metal feed pipe as people suggest or can I use plastic?

As I understand it, the distance the water can be pumped is a function of the force that the water in the feed pipe can exert. The rule of thumb is to make the feed pipe twice the output pipe, but if I had two feed pipes, would that not  double the force, and there fore double the distance?

What is the purpose of the stand pipe, will a stand pipe increase the distance the pup will pump?

Here are some of the resources I've found

https://www.bae.ncsu.edu/extension/ext-publications/water/use/ebae-161-92-ram-pump-jennings.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4y_WWxWdn5A

as well as numerous other youtube videos, describing the construction but not the theory.

Comment: So, you say you have seen a lot of stuff online - what and where so people don't waste time and effort repeating what you have already found / read etc.

Comment: I added few It still does not explain things like if and why the stand pipe improves performance, or if adding two feed pipes would effect the inflow and therefore the performance.

Comment: I'm not expert enough to do a full answer, but the input pipe needs to be stiff - the pump 'works' by generating a pressure pulse and you want the pressure in the pump to remain high for as long as possible, so as much as possible flows through the non-return valve into the delivery side.  The pressure stays high while the pulse propagates back up the inlet pipe - if the inlet pipe is flexible that pressure will dissipate in stretching the pipe, so you want as rigid and as long an inlet pipe as possible.  It might work with plastic, it will work better the more rigid the inlet.